# Check if all list items exist in line(regex)

Tags: python, regex

I know that the OR condition in a regex is "|"
e.g.

```
re.search(r"(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)", line):
```

to find if a line contains reference to a month.

How about if we want all the items to exist in a line(or str)? For now I have something like this

```
    if re.search(r"ERRO", line) and re.search(r"MainThread:", line):
```

but I might want to add more conditionals. Moreover what if those items exist in a list and we don't want to iterate through the list? Is there a pythonic way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use regex for that purpose. Regex is helpful when you have patterns, not simple Strings. For example, you would use regex if you want to extract numbers inside parenthesis from a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `all` it will evaluate lazily.

```
conditions = ["foo","bar"]

s = "foo bar"
print all(x in s.split()  for x in conditions)
True

l = ["fo","bar"]

s = "foo bar"
print all(x in s.split() for x in conditions)
False
```

If you don't split the words, words like `fo` will be considered to be in the line so split or don't split based on what you consider being in the line:

```
conditions = ["fo","bar"]

s = "foo bar"
print all(x in s  for x in conditions)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

`and` conditions are expressed with lookaheads in regexp language:

```
import re

print re.search(r'^(?=.*foo)(?=.*baz)(?=.*bar)', "foo and bar and baz")   # ok
print re.search(r'^(?=.*foo)(?=.*baz)(?=.*bar)', "foo and bar and spam")  # nope
```

If you have a list of keywords, you can create this regex dynamically

```
keywords = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
regex = '^' + ''.join("(?=.*%s)" % s for s in keywords)
```

Of course, if you're only looking for literal strings, `all(word in string for word in words)` would be simpler (not necessarily faster).

Comment: both, helped me thanks. The only thing I want to figure out now is how to add the "r" in front of the variable

Comment: You don't need (and can't) use `r` for variables - it's literal syntax.

Comment: yeah, I figured it out around 15 secs after I wrote this. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `in` operator:

```
if "ERRO" in line and "MainThread:" in line:
```

If you keep the keywords in a list, you check them all using the `all` function:

```
keywords = ["ERRO", "MainThread", ...]    
if all(k in line for k in keywords):
```